# Laravel 4 to Microsoft SQL server remote

Tags: sql-server-2008, ubuntu, laravel-4, ubuntu-12.04

I'm trying to connect Laravel (Server: Ubuntu 12.04 x64) to remote Microsoft SQL server 2008 R2. 
I'm using sqlsrv.

```
'sqlsrv' => array(
        'driver'   => 'sqlsrv',
        'host'     => 'localhost',
        'database' => 'test',
        'username' => 'sa',
        'password' => 'pass',
        'prefix'   => '',
    ),
```

how can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As your SQL Server database is on a remote server, let's say 192.168.1.23 replace the 'host' field value with 192.168.1.23 and your SQL Server credentials on the 'username' and 'password' fileds, let's say username: sa and password: asecurepassword

```
'sqlsrv' => array(
    'driver'   => 'sqlsrv',
    'host'     => '192.168.1.23',
    'database' => 'your_database_name',
    'username' => 'sa',
    'password' => 'asecurepassword',
    'prefix'   => '',
),
```